# Can 'Zefal All in 1' really doall of those: cleaning, degreasing and oiling?

Tags: maintenance, repair, preventative-maintenance, restoration

Can someone tell me if 'Zefal' All in 1 Spray is good for: degreasing, oiling and cleaning? [Link](http://www.zefal.com/en/maintain/136-bike-all-in-1.html)

It seems suspicious because it covers 4 very distinct functions in a single spray; eg: Degreasing, Oiling, Cleaning.

What do you'll think?

I just got a beautiful bike yesterday, powerful and smooth pedalling. However, it was very neglected and needs cleaning and rustproofing. However, as a student I don't have a tremendously large budget and this bike needs some other purchases too.

Comment: It claims to do +grease and -grease (oil).  It's not going to be very good at either.  What it will do is dilute what's there allowing you to wipe some of the muck off.

Comment: It sounds like it should be really expensive, if it has been engineered to do all that at different periods.  If its cheap, its just WD40 or CRC556 with a different name.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's better to avoid spray-type lubricants like this one (plus, it won't do any of the functions described well). They have a tendency to go in places you don't want to go. Look for drip bottles, such as this one:

[image: triflow]

If you're on a budget, good old 3-in-1 multipurpose oil is about 2 dollars (versus bicycle branded ones being about 5-6 for a lot less). It's better than nothing.

---

If you need to restore things like a rusted chain (and for some reason don't want to spend the 10 dollars to replace it), you can clean the rust off with citrus cleaner or mineral spirits then oil it. Bits of rust on the frame aren't really a big deal unless they're huge amounts bad enough to have structural effects.

Comment: My outside/beater bike gets GT85 spray on the chain and sprockets, because I don't have cleaning facilities (it's in another city) and I want to keep rust on moving parts to a minimum - a surface coating seems to help with that.  For any decent bike kept in sensible conditions I agree with you.

Comment: Thank you! I will look for generic drip oil for the chain, an amateur question, but I would still need grease for the chains no? @Batman

Comment: No -- the oil is the only lubricant you need. Just oil it periodically and wipe it down when its dirty.

Comment: Okay, so I will de-grease and oil with WD-40, that sound about right?

Comment: @user2440943: I guess you mean "WD-40 Bike Chain Lubricant" rather than "WD-40 Multi-Use Product"

Comment: If you want to clean the chain, see [my answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36873/chain-lube-that-wont-repaint-my-legs/36874#36874) to another question.