# Can I use silicon spray to lubricate my hybrid cycle chain?

Tags: lubricant

Can I use silicon spray to lubricate my hybrid cycle chain? (Of course,  after de-greasing it using a de-greasing spray)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Better use a specific Teflon based dry chain lubricant.

Comment: If you want a "clean" lube, I prefer something that describes itself as "wax".  There are various formulations that contain wax mixed with some fluid that evaporates after application.

Comment: I do 20 kilometres a day, 7 days a week. After reading all the answers, I have decided to use regular drip lubricant and wipe the chain with a rag as frequently as possible. Thank you, Daniel,Nate, B Team and Batman for your inputs.

Answer (score 5):

*Can you?* Yes. It is not optimal for use on chains though. It washes away rather easily leaving your chain unprotected and un-lubricated. It would work in a pinch but a light oil or something specifically made for the application will work much better and last a lot longer.

Wet or Dry lubes depend on the riding conditions and where you live. WD40 makes a good bicycle chain lube, their bike line, not the generic stuff in a can. Don't use that. RocknRoll, Triflow, ProGold all also makes good lubes.

Answer (score 2):

I dissent. Yes, you can use a silicone lube. Is it as good as a bike specific product? That depends on how much you ride and what conditions. I use Dumonde's Bicycle Chain Lube and it is great in the worst of conditions. It goes 300 miles between relubes. I love it. But it is overkill for a hybrid doing 20 miles a week. It doesn't make sense financially (cost of lube) compared to your needs.

It is better to carefully lube your chain with what you have than not to lube at all. The key is to be clean. Wipe the chain off with an old clothe after every ride or two, and especially after ever application.

And I have used WD-40 in wet club races. It works great as I recognize what it is good for. Your bike will not burst into flames using WD-40 so long as you realize it is not for a century distance, or once a month lubrication.

Answer (score 1):

First, on degreasing: Manufacturers have recommendations for cleaning your chain. [One suggests](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36873/chain-lube-that-wont-repaint-my-legs/36874#36874) not using anything more than a bit of soapy water when necessary, along with a brush. Another suggests a gentle degreaser or neutral detergent, etc. I wouldn't use a degreaser spray on the bike lest it get somewhere it shouldn't. In fact, I probably wouldn't apply the degreaser at all, but maybe wipe it with a damp rag and let it dry before lubricating.

Sprays are generally a bad idea for bicycles -- they tend to get on places where you don't want them to. If you could ideally lubricate a chain, you'd use the wax system they use at the factory. But since that's insane to do at home, your best bet is a drip bottle (like most bicycle lubes are sold) for oiling the chain. The drip bottle is about as quick as doing a spray, most likely, and would leave less of a mess.

As for silicone, I'd stick with a regular bicycle lubricant (e.g. Triflow, or something based on what kind of riding conditions you have), or if you're on a budget, 3-in-1 oil (a lot of places don't recommend it, but its cheap and it does lubricate). It isn't clear to me that silicone spray has the ability to lubricate bike chains for an appreciable amount of time, especially in non-ideal wet conditions.