# Cleaning and lubing bicycle chain with diesel

Tags: chain, cleaning

For last 3 weeks I am using diesel for my cleaning and lubing my bicycle chain, so far I am not facing any problems.

Should I continue this or am I damaging my chains ?

Has anyone else using this method ?

Answer (score 14):

3 weeks isn't likely enough for you to damage the chain noticeably (rattling sounds and all that jazz) unless you're putting particularly heavy mileage.

This isn't something I'd recommend doing; diesel fuel doesn't have the right lubricating properties for a bicycle chain. It's also not the most pleasant stuff to be around.

Diesel will act as a degreaser which will clean the chain, but this is against most chain manufacturer's recommendations to begin with (which I've outlined [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/36873/chain-lube-that-wont-repaint-my-legs/36874#36874)).

I'd suggest following the directions of the manufacturer and using a bicycle specific chain lube (or 3-in-1 if you want to save money), and a damp cloth to periodically wipe down the chain after riding and re-lubricating. I do own a chain washing machine, but it hasn't been used in quite a while.

Comment: Concur - chain cleaners are fairly useless and only do 1/4 of the cleaning.

Comment: I love my chain cleaner, it gets the outside nice and shiny and looking new :).